How to reply only to teams posts not threads with bot?
I have built a small Azure Bot based on Python according to the documentation
Basically what bot does? It just automatically replies to messages in Teams channel reacting to specific kewords ,here is the code
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext

class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        user_message = turn_context.activity.text.lower()
      
        
        lock_keywords = ['locked', 'unlock', 'blocked', 'locking', 'lock', 'login', 'connect', 'vpn']
        password_keywords = ['password', 'expired', 'credentials']
        duo_keywords = ['duo', '2fa']
        
        # Convert user's message to lowercase for case-insensitive matching
        user_message_lower = user_message.lower()
        
        
        # Check for specific keyword groups and send corresponding responses
        if any(word in user_message_lower for word in lock_keywords):
            response_message = ("Hi,\n\n"
                                "If you are enrolled to SSPR you can now unlock yourself with this link:\n"
                                "https://confluence.infobip.com/display/CWT/Self+service+password+reset+-+add+additional+sign-in+method\n\n"
                                "If you are not enrolled, here is the link to enroll:\n"
                                "https://confluence.infobip.com/display/CWT/Self+service+password+reset+-+add+additional+sign-in+method\n\n"
                                "If it helped, write resolved,   if not, write help")
            
            await turn_context.send_activity(response_message)
        
        if any(word in user_message_lower for word in password_keywords):
            await turn_context.send_activity("If your password is expired you can reset it using this link: https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/ChangePassword.aspx")
        
        if any(word in user_message_lower for word in duo_keywords):
            await turn_context.send_activity("If you need to re-enroll in DUO 2FA, please raise a ticket here: https://jira.infobip.com/")



The question is how to reply only 1 time so after  post the bot will not keep replying to the messages reacting to keywords like vpn or password as you can see from the screenshot
what I tried ?
import logging
from botbuilder.core import ActivityHandler, TurnContext

# Configure logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # Set the logging level to DEBUG

class MyBot(ActivityHandler):
    
    async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
        # Check if the activity is from Microsoft Teams
        if turn_context.activity.channel_id != 'msteams':
            return  # Exit the function to skip processing
        
        # Check if the activity is a channel message (not a thread)
        if turn_context.activity.conversation.conversation_type != 'channel':
            return  # Exit the function to skip processing
        
        # Check if the activity is a reply (part of a thread)
        if turn_context.activity.reply_to_id:
            # This is a thread message
            logger.info("It is a thread message")
            return
        
        # This is a top-level channel message (post)
        logger.info("It is a post message")
       ..

Still bot can't differentiate channel posts from threads

Can you try storing the message Id or original thread.

To answer in a Teams channel post only one time in the threads with an Azure bot, you can follow these steps:
Detect the scope of the message to determine if it is a channel message.
Check if the message is a reply to an existing thread. You can do this by examining the conversation.id property of the message. If it contains the ID of the first message in the thread, it means it is a reply to the thread.
If the message is a reply to the thread, you can use the ReplyToActivity method in .NET or the session.send method in Node.js to send a reply to the thread. Make sure to include the conversation.id in the reply to ensure it is posted in the correct thread.
If the message is not a reply to the thread, you can ignore it or handle it differently based on your bot's logic.
Please note that the specific implementation details may vary depending on the programming language and framework you are using to build your Azure bot.
Reference doc link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-channel
